# Iterate multiple dat files, update and save in a separate directory as separate files

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm reading multiple dat files, setting a "name" column as nan. I need to save these updated files separately in another directory. They should not be saved as a single file.

Current code:

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob(filepath+'time*.dat'))
for f in filenames:
    print(f)
    data = pd.read_csv(f, sep='|', skiprows=1)
    for d in data:
        data['name']=np.nan
        data.to_csv('D:\\abc.dat',sep='|')
```

Comment: You don’t need the second loop and just pass file name as variable in data.to_csv. Then you should be good

Comment: No it is not happening. Here I need to read each *.dat file separately, update separately (with same change) and create a new *.dat file with the same name in a different directory. I've around 1500 *.dat files to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I assume you should be looking for something like this. In the loop, first read file, then do your changes, and save in a seperate file in another directory.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
filenames = sorted(glob.glob(filepath+'time*.dat'))
for f in filenames:
    print(f)
    data = pd.read_csv(f, sep='|', skiprows=1)
    data['name']=np.nan
    data.to_csv('D:\\'+os.path.basename(f) ,sep='|')
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I just made a change >> data.to_csv('D:\\'+os.basename(f) ,sep='|')    changed to >> data.to_csv('D:\\'+os.path.basename(f) ,sep='|')